# change class if value greater then defined value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the class of an element depending on the value. Is it possible to do this inside the loop?

Javascript:

```
$.post(url, filteredObject, function (data2) {
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).text(numberWithCommas(data2[i].TY));
        $('#sdly' + (i + 1).toString()).text(numberWithCommas(data2[i].SDLY));
        $('#fcst' + (i + 1).toString()).text(numberWithCommas(data2[i].FCSTYTD));
    }
});
```

I tried something like this but didn't work.

```
var textvalue = parseInt($('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).text)
if (textvalue < 0) {
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).toggleClass("fa fa-level-down");
}
else {
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).toggleClass("fa fa-level-up");
}
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Describe "doesn't work".

Comment: Does your id selectors working correctly. If it is working correctly please change toggle class by addclass and removeclass and verify if it is working.

Comment: well, previously the values would be placed in there own td since doing this function all the values are appending to ty1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use "toggleClass"

> .toggleClass( className )
>
> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence [...]

it removes the class if it is present and adds it if it is not, so achieve that you only have one of `fa-level-down` and `fa-level-up` you should use `.addClass( className )` and `.removeClass( className )`

```
var textvalue = parseInt($('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).text)
if (textvalue < 0) {
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).addClass("fa-level-down");
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).removeClass("fa-level-up");
}
else {
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).addClass("fa-level-up");
    $('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).removeClass("fa-level-down");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets after `.text` on the line:

```
var textvalue = parseInt($('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).text)
```

You should use `.text()` to get the text of a jQuery object.

```
var textvalue = parseInt($('#ty' + (i + 1).toString()).text())
```

Comment: you are correct, was the final touch for it to all work! thank you